# How to destroy a line when line renderer is used in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

So I only want one line on screen at a time. I would like to destroy the current line when a ball collides or another line is drawn. Here is my code so far. It creates a line renderer with two points, adds a Box collider. I've tried making a loop and setting the vector points back to zero.

Every time I add a `OnCollisonEnter2D` I cannot get the Line to register that it hit a ball. In the Ball script I can get the Log to print Hit when the Ball hits the collider.

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using UnityEditor.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Player1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    private LineRenderer line; // Reference to LineRenderer
    private Vector3 mousePos;
    public  Vector3 startPos;    // Start position of line
    public  Vector3 endPos;    // End position of line

    void Update()
    {
        GetLine(); // On mouse down new line will be created 
    }

    private void GetLine()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if (line == null)
                CreateLine();
                SetFirstPos();
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            if (line)
            {
                SetSecondPos();
                AddColliderToLine();
                line = null;
            }
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            if (line)
            {
                mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
                mousePos.z = 0;
                line.SetPosition(1, mousePos);
            }
        }
    }

    // Following method creates line runtime using Line Renderer component
    private void CreateLine()
    {
        line = new GameObject("Line").AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        line.positionCount = 2;
        line.numCapVertices = 2;
        line.startWidth = .25f;
        line.endWidth = .25f;
        line.startColor = Color.black;
        line.endColor = Color.black;
        line.useWorldSpace = true;
    }
    // Following method adds collider to created line
    private void AddColliderToLine()
    {
        BoxCollider2D col = new GameObject("Collider").AddComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        col.transform.parent = line.transform; // Collider is added as child object of line
        float lineLength = Vector3.Distance(startPos, endPos);// length of line
        lineLength.ToString();
        col.size = new Vector3(lineLength, 0.25f, 1f); // size of collider is set where X is length of 
        line, Y is width of line, Z will be set as per requirement
        Vector3 midPoint = (startPos + endPos) / 2;
        col.transform.position = midPoint; // setting position of collider object
        // Following lines calculate the angle between startPos and endPos
        float angle = (Mathf.Abs(startPos.y - endPos.y) / Mathf.Abs(startPos.x - endPos.x));
        if ((startPos.y < endPos.y && startPos.x > endPos.x) || (endPos.y < startPos.y && endPos.x > 
        startPos.x))
        {
            angle *= -1;
        }
        angle = Mathf.Rad2Deg * Mathf.Atan(angle);
        col.transform.Rotate(0, 0, angle);
    }
    //Sets the first position
    private void SetFirstPos()
    {
        mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        mousePos.z = 0;
        line.SetPosition(0, mousePos);
        startPos = mousePos;
        Debug.Log("Line");
    }
    //Sets the second position
    private void SetSecondPos()
    {
        mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        mousePos.z = 0;
        line.SetPosition(1, mousePos);
        endPos = mousePos;
    }
    //Cannot get it to Log Hit. Line show up in the Hierarchy.
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameobject.name =="Line")
        {
            Debug.Log("Hit!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Lunchbox, welcome to Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is for knowledge based questions regarding technologies and application. Your question is is implementational and doesn't provide the community with any specific insights and knowledge. It reads as though this is a homework question.I'd suggest you focus on basic coding techniques, and use the debugger to step through your code the understand why it is not working as you except. Also, please do not format your question in large fonts., Use the standard font. Jimbob

Answer (score 0):

If your `OnCollisionEnter2D` gets called why don't you use just use it?

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.name =="Line")
    {
        Debug.Log("Hit!");
        // destroy the hit line
        GameObject.Destroy(collision.gameObject);
    }
}
```

If you want the line to be destroyed once a new one gets created you have to store it and destroy it manually:

```
public class Player1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject lastLine;
    [...]

    private void GetLine()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if(lastLine != null)
            {
                GameObject.Destroy(lastLine);
            }
            if (line == null)
                CreateLine();
            SetFirstPos();
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            if (line)
            {
                SetSecondPos();
                AddColliderToLine();
                lastLine = line.gameObject;
                line = null;
            }
        }
        [...]
    }
```